# Interruptible sleep in std::thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11, sleep, condition-variable, stdthread

I have a simple C++11 thread program like below.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   std::cout << "My program starts" << std::endl;
   std::atomic<bool> exit_thread(false);
   std::thread my_thread = std::thread([&exit_thread]{
        do {
            std::cout << "Thread is doing something..." << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
        } while (!exit_thread);
    });

   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(12));
   exit_thread = true;
   std::cout << "Might have to wait to exit thread" << std::endl;
   my_thread.join();
   return 0;
}
```

As you can see above, there is a loop which has a `sleep_for` which makes the thread sleep for 5 seconds and then it wakes and loops again provided that `exit_thread` is set to false. Main thread waits for 12 seconds and prepares to exit firstly by setting `exit_thread` to true and then does a `join` on the thread. All good until now.

**Problem:**
Above is okay and works for objective. **But** there is a "potential problem". If the thread has just now started to sleep then it would take it 4 seconds more before it gets out of sleep to discover that it now needs to exit. This delays the exit process and destruction.

**Question:**
How to can I make the thread sleep in an interruptible way? So that I can interrupt the sleep and make the thread exit right away instead by cancelling out of sleep instead of waiting for the potential 4 or 3 or 2 seconds.

I think that the solution to this might be achievable using a [std::condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)? Probably? I am looking for a piece of code to show how.

**Note** that my code runs on both clang and gcc.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to wait on a semaphore or condition variable with a timeout, instead of sleeping unconditionally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We should be waiting on a condition variable or semaphore instead of sleeping.  Here's the minimal change to do that:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "My program starts" << std::endl;
   std::atomic<bool> exit_thread(false);
   std::condition_variable cv;
   std::mutex m;

   std::thread my_thread = std::thread([&exit_thread,&cv,&m]{
        do {
            std::cout << "Thread is doing something..." << std::endl;
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
                cv.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(5));
            }
        } while (!exit_thread);
    });

   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(12));
   {
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);
       exit_thread = true;
   }
   cv.notify_all();

   std::cout << "Thread stops immediately" << std::endl;
   my_thread.join();
}
```

Apparently, we do need the mutex:

> Even if the shared variable is atomic, it must be modified under the
>   mutex in order to correctly publish the modification to the waiting
>   thread.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot. And the spurious wakeup issue with `std::condition_variable`s is not an issue to bother about in this solution? Only just need this confirmation before accepting this answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip on the atomic variable. If I use `load()` and `store(value)` technique then I don't need a mutex? Probably this is a question for a different SO discussion.

Comment: Whether you need to deal with spurious wakeup is something you'll have to decide - if you really can't start the next iteration of the loop before 5 seconds are up, then you'll have to check for it, else not.  I think you'd still need the mutex with atomic `load()`/`store()`, as `cv.wait_for` takes the lock as its first argument - but ask another question for a more informed answer!  I'm no expert here.

Comment: >Even if the shared variable is atomic,
Can you explain me please how the mutex is protecting the read of `exit_thread` variable?

Comment: @Kamil_H, acquiring and releasing `lock` acts as a memory barrier for the `std::atomic` variable.